# How can I avoid repeating some part of the statement in this LINQ

Tags: linq

```
User.Where(u => new int[]{1,2}.Contains(u.Org_id)).GroupBy(u => u.Org_id)
.Select(g => new {GroupId = g.Key, UserCount =  g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1).Count(), Users = g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1)})
.Take(500)
```

This part `g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1)` of the statement is repeated, how can I avoid repeating that?

Comment: Move the where out and after the groupby

Comment: Don't store the `Count()`, call `ToList()` on the result and then you have the list and the `Count`. Alternatively project the list twice, once to Key and Users where Role = 1, and then again to the result you want.

Comment: @Nkosi it would need to be before the GroupBy() to operate on the users directly and if you did that you wouldn't get empty-set results (count = 0).

Comment: @IanMercer yeah, I eventually realized that when iI thought it over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1: don't store the count (it's redundant):

```
User.Where(u => new int[]{1,2}.Contains(u.Org_id))
    .GroupBy(u => u.Org_id)
    .Select(g => new {GroupId = g.Key, Users = g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1).ToList()})
    .Take(500)
```

option 2: project twice:

```
User.Where(u => new int[]{1,2}.Contains(u.Org_id))
    .GroupBy(u => u.Org_id)
    .Select(g => new {GroupId = g.Key, Users = g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1).ToList()})
    .Select(x => new {GroupId = x.GroupId, Users = x.Users, UserCount = x.Users.Count})
    .Take(500)
```

Comment: `The expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LINQPad.User.User]' is not a sequence` but if I remove this `UserCount = x.Users.Count` query is successful but no UserCount

Comment: @HeeroYuy LinqPad issue? Works fine in .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Uz7qM

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating the delegate

For example

```
User.Where(u => new int[]{1,2}.Contains(u.Org_id))
.GroupBy(u => u.Org_id) 
.Select(g => {
    var items = g.Where(gu => gu.Role == 1);
    return new {GroupId = g.Key, UserCount =  items.Count(), Users = items };
})
.Take(500);
```

Comment: this works but I had to add `.AsEnumerable()` after GroupBy, thank you